# How to ignore the first action in the gtest DoAll()

Tags: c++, reference, googletest, googlemock

I declare a function

```
void MyFunction(const std::wstring& inParameter, std::wstring& outParamater);
```

The first parameter is a passed in parameter, the second one is the value out parameter, the value I want to get by the function will pass it out by `outParameter`.

Now I Gmock it

```
MOCK_METHOD2(MyFunction, void(const std::wstring&, std::wstring&));
```

However, when I use this mock function:

```
std::wstring firstStr = L"firstStr";
std::wstring test = L"test";
EXPECT_CALL(*myGmockInstance, MyFunction(firstStr, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(DoAll(firstStr, SetArgReferee<1>(test)));
```

It doesn't work.

I also tried

```
EXPECT_CALL(*myGmockInstance, MyFunction(_, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(DoAll(_, SetArgReferee<1>(test)));
```

or

```
EXPECT_CALL(*myGmockInstance, MyFunction(_, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(DoAll(firstStr, SetArgReferee<1>(test)));
```

or

```
EXPECT_CALL(*myGmockInstance, MyFunction(_, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(firstStr), SetArgReferee<1>(test)));
```

I understand that the `inParameter` is `const`, so I cannot use `SetArgReferee` for it. But how to set its value and at the same time I can set value for `outParameter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the title of your question is quite misleading. From what I understand, you just want to assign some arbitrary value to your function's second argument (the output argument). This is how you can do it using `Invoke`:

```
using ::testing::_;

void assignStringToArg(const std::wstring&, std::wstring& outputStr,
    const std::wstring expectedStr) {
    outputStr = expectedStr;
}

class SomeMock {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(MyFunction, void(const std::wstring&, std::wstring&));
};

TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    SomeMock someMock;
    std::wstring firstStr(L"aaabbbccc");
    std::wstring secondStr(L"I should change upon MyFunction call ...");
    std::wstring expectedSecondStr(L"xxxyyyzzz");
    EXPECT_CALL(someMock, MyFunction(firstStr, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(Invoke(std::bind(
        &assignStringToArg,
        std::placeholders::_1,
        std::placeholders::_2,
        expectedSecondStr)));
    someMock.MyFunction(firstStr, secondStr);
    ASSERT_EQ(expectedSecondStr, secondStr);
}
```

Note that the function provided to `Invoke` must have the same signature as the function that you expect to be called (that's why I use `bind`). You can achieve the same result using google macro `ACTION_P`. I prefer to use `Invoke` only because it looks more clean to me.

Since your case is rather simple, you can also do it using `SetArgReferee` like you tried before:

```
    EXPECT_CALL(someMock, MyFunction(firstStr, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(
        SetArgReferee<1>(L"something"));
    someMock.MyFunction(firstStr, secondStr);
    ASSERT_EQ(L"something", secondStr);
```

I just see no point using `DoAll` if you only want to do one action. But ... if you really insist:

```
    EXPECT_CALL(someMock, MyFunction(firstStr, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(
        DoAll(SetArgReferee<1>(L"something1"), SetArgReferee<1>(L"something2")));
    someMock.MyFunction(firstStr, secondStr);
    ASSERT_EQ(L"something2", secondStr);
```

It is rather stupid example, because it set's the output variable to `L"something1"` and then immediately to `L"something2"`.